# What's wrong with my HWIOAUTHBUNDLE config?

Tags: hwioauthbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm using Symfony 3.4 with FOSUSERBundle, my facebook button was working and then suddenly nothing. Just ***"No oauth code in the request"*** message.

Can someone tell me where my config is incorrect, or share a config that will work?

**/config.yml**

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: ["main"]
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook: facebook_id

    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:           facebook
            client_id:      "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3"
            client_secret:  "exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6"
            scope:         email
            infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,gender,last_name,first_name,birthday,picture.type(square)"

            options:
                csrf: true
```

**/routing.yml**

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix:   /

facebook_login:
    path: /connect/check-facebook
```

**/security.yml**

```
security:

    #...

    firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            #...

            #HWIOAuthBundle
            oauth:
                login_path:     /login
                failure_path:   /login
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/connect/check-facebook"
```

**/services.yml**

```
services:
    app.fos_user.oauth_provider:
        # Change the class according to the location of the FOSUBUserProvider class
        class: EC\UserBundle\Entity\FOSUBUserProvider
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager',{facebook: facebook_id}]
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution ?